# Auto generated taxonomy trees

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there a module to generate taxonomy trees (with links to taxonomy pages) ?

(And to automatically update them if new tags are added / removed from the list ?)

ps. I'm talking about the front-end. I'm already using taxonomy manager that allows me to handle tags hierarchies from back-end

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with this module: drupal.org/project/vocabindex

However, I would like to display the tree automatically expanded, and the parents should have the link to the parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a module to generate taxonomy trees (with links to taxonomy pages) ?

No, there isn't. Views allows you to create a list of taxonomy terms, but the list is not shown as a tree.